# Using a different version of WebBrowser control

Tags: .net, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-11

I just wanted to create a simple visual basic application to test that I can create programs that embed webpages.

However, I have noticed that the renderer for the WebBrowser control may be different from the one used in IE11 (which I have installed).

For one thing, on IE11, the scroll bars look different.

When I visit [this page](http://www.whatbrowser.org/), it tells me I'm on IE11 when I use IE11, and then tells me I'm on IE7 when I use the WebBrowser control.

I've also found some websites telling me I could fix it by changing some registry values for the application. But it seemed rather silly to me that I couldn't specify this in my code.

I don't mind switching to C++, C# or some other `.NET` language. Is there a way I can programmatically change the version of IE that is being used by `WebBrowser`?

Comment: The only way to do that is by setting the registry values for your application. The webbrowser control is really an instance of IE. It reads those entries to determine how to show web pages by application. And if you distribute your app, your app will used the currently installed version of IE on the customer's machine. It will not automatically upgrade to your version.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the browser emulation (the default is IE8) for your app in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

See here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)